# Automatically Paste a cell value into the last row of another googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a sheet named 'Titles' in column C values are constantly being entered. Once a value is entered in column C, I need that newest value to automatically be copied into the sheet named 'Translations' in Column D at the next available row (beneath the latest value copied).

As values are being pasted in 'Titles' column C how can this script constantly be running, so I don't need to click run a script every time for the new title to display in the translations sheet.

function I have so far copying from another case

```
function copyPaste() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('Titles');
  var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('Translations');
  var srcrg=srcsh.getRange('C2:C1000');
  var data=srcrg.getValues();
  var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessh.getLastRow() + 1,1,99,1);
  desrg.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make this a installable trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Titles' && e.range.columnStart==3) {
    e.source.toast('past conditional');//etc
    const tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Translations');
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,4).setValue(e.value);//e.value is the value added to columnC of 'Title' sheet
  }
}
```

Comment: When I add this in the script editor and run, I get this following error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: You cannot run functions that contain trigger event objects without replacing the objects yourself.  I do this sometimes to debug the code but generally I just do that in place by making the appropriate edits and use `e.source.toast()` to track my progress.;  See the change I made in the code to show you what I mean

Comment: can you provide steps on how to get this working in my googlesheet. I had save that script as a triggered event onChange. However it does not work yet.

Comment: I created it as you can see as an onEdit(e) function so that's the first step because you need the correct event object.

Comment: In order to get to the 'past conditional' toast you will have to be editing columnC of sheet 'Titles'

Comment: e.value is the new value added to columnC and it is sent to the bottom of columnD in 'Translations' sheet.

Comment: Oh and I meant to ask how often is Column C of Titles being edited by Users?

Comment: when I save the function and hit run, I immediately get the error notice. When I go to my sheet and add a value in Column C in Titles I just get a dialogue pop up on bottom that says 'entry' and no values copy to Column D in Translations.
Column C has approx. 20 values being added per hour.

Comment: You can't run this from script editor so don't try it's a waste of time.  So the good news is that you are getting to the function my editing column C because you're seeing entry.  Do you know why you're see 'entry' in the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I think it may run now.  I found an error in there.